# "JavaFX 1.3 Async Task" in JavaFX 2.0 ? PostMessage method (how-to-update-my-code)

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I was using JavaFX 1.2 last year. As the Model part of my app was in Java I've used this method that worked very well : http://blogs.oracle.com/clarkeman/entry/javafx_async_task
to push some data from a java task to a JavaFX app (example: status of the java task presented as a ProgressionBar in the JavaFX app).

Problem is now with the brand new JavaFX 2.0...
How do I update my code to make it working as it did with javaFX 1.2 ?

Example of my code - this is how I was sending notifications from Java class implementing RunnableFuture to my JavaFX code:

```
//in the MyRunnable.java
    private void postMessage(final String msg) {
        Entry.deferAction(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                listener.callback(msg);
            }
        });
    }
```

How my JavaFX2.0 code can now be updated of some information I am treating in the Java task ?

Comment: This question become a mess. Why edit it instead of creating another one? Asking questions is free. And new question can have title relevant to the content unlike this updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
private void postMessage(final String msg) {
    javafx.application.Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            listener.callback(msg);
        }
    });
}
```